# connect to client in netty in channelhandler

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to connect to another client from a server I'm building in Netty.  I looked at the proxy example here: http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/proxy/package-summary.html

So in my subclass of `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`, I try to do this

```
ctx.pipeline().addLast(new EchoTestHandler("localhost", 3030));
```

My EchoTestHandler looks like:

```
public class EchoTestHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private final String host;
    private final int port;
    private Channel outboundChannel;

    public EchoTestHandler(String host, int port) {
        System.out.println("constructor echo test handler");
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("channel test handler");

        final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();

        // start the connection attempt
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
                .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
                .handler(new CryptoServerHandler(inboundChannel));
        ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(host, port);
        outboundChannel = future.channel();
        future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture) {
                if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
                    // connection complete, start to read first data
                    inboundChannel.read();
                } else {
                    // close the connection if connection attempt has failed
                    inboundChannel.close();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The constructor gets called, but since it does not connect  to anything yet, `channelActive` never gets called.  I also tried this, more similar to the proxy example:

```
ctx.pipeline().addLast(new EchoServerInitializer("localhost", 3020));
```

And then EchoServerInitializer:

```
public class EchoServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    private final String host;
    private final int port;

    public EchoServerInitializer(String host, int port) {
        System.out.println("constructor EchoServerInitializer");
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
        System.out.println("EchoServerInitializer initChannel");
        ch.pipeline().addLast(
                new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO),
                new EchoServerHandler()
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect with something to your proxy server to perform `channelActive` call. Proxy example uses `8443` port, so you can connect via telnet (or somethig else) using command `telnet localhost 8443`.

Comment: I have another server up and running